# CXXFLAGS has changed since the previous run when building gdb

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, gdb

In my situation, I build gdb with 
`./configure --prefix=/home/vv/Desktop/gdb --enable-static=yes`. 
but it doesn't support python, so I try to recompile gdb with 
`./configure --prefix=/home/vv/Desktop/gdb --enable-static=yes --with-python`
 However, I get this error:

```
configure: loading cache ./config.cache
configure: error: `CXXFLAGS' has changed since the previous run:
configure:   former value:  `  '
configure:   current value: `-g -O2    '
configure: error: in `/home/vv/Desktop/gdb-12.1/gdbsupport':
configure: error: changes in the environment can compromise the build
configure: error: run `make distclean' and/or `rm ./config.cache' and start over
make[1]: *** [configure-gdbsupport] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vv/Desktop/gdb-12.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I had tried `make distclean` or `rm ./config.cache`. And configure and make again. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I delete the whole folder. And extract gdb source files again. And configure and make, this time, it works well.

Comment: It is a good idea not to configure and build in the source directory.  One approach is to place the build directory in parallel to the source directory, i.e. `work-dir/src` and `work-dir/build`.  Then, from the build directory do `../src/configure ....options....`.
The benefit of this approach is that if/when you need a clean build you can `rm -fr *` in the build directory, and your source directory is untouched.

Comment: @Andrew good advise.